# ¿Es necesario mencionar que un enlace es en inglés?

Tags: discusión

En mi [primera pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/12/22), mencioné un enlace a StackOverflow en inglés:

> Ya sé que [es fácil suprimir el mensaje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346640/13860) con ...

Después alguién más lo editó para añadir "(en inglés)":

> Ya sé que [es fácil suprimir el mensaje (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346640/13860) con ...

No me molesta el cambio, solo me pregunto si ¿de verdad es necesario?  Puedo imaginar que un gran porción de nuestras preguntas van a tener enlaces a recursos en inglés, y puede ser un fuente de mucho ruido de modificaciones si 
siempre estamos añadiendo "(en inglés)".

Yo supongo que, a veces, es agradable mencionar cuando un enlace es para otro idioma (Alemán, Japonés, o como sea) que no puedo leer.  Pero en esa industria, casi es obligatorio leer, por lo menos, un poco en inglés.

Entonces me parece un poco gratuito decir "(en inglés)".

En otro lado, si citamos algo de una fuente inglés, creo que, por lo menos, deberíamos traducir la porción relevante.

Comment: para mi no es necesario, y la verdad no me gusta como se ve. fue un experimento que hice para ver como se veía el post. También edite la otra respuesta y no se ve nada bien, introduce un ruido innecesario, no constructivo.

Comment: @rnrneverdies yo acepte tu edicion pero por lo que puedo leer esta de mas, asi que la voy a resturar por si alguien la tomase de guia Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel dele nomas, que sea rock!

Answer (score 13):

Una buena alternativa sería hacer que este tipo de enlaces siempre tengan como texto el título del artículo o página que se cita:

> Más información aquí: [TypeScript Classes and Interfaces](http://www.johnpapa.net/typescriptpost3)

...o en caso de preguntas y respuestas de StackOverflow, el título de la pregunta:

> Ya sé que es fácil suprimir el mensaje (["Perl idiom for getting a maximum number of elements in an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346640/13860)) con...

Esto hace que el problema desaparezca porque resulta obvio el idioma del texto enlazado, y además es una práctica recomendada para enlaces de páginas web en general ya que facilita el uso de herramientas de accesibilidad, por ejemplo las que leen en voz alta los enlaces (lo siento, no recuerdo dónde lo leí).

Comment: Intentemos solamente citar la fuente del enlace cuando sea posible como lo menciono @konamiman.  No es necesario agregar (inglés) en los enlaces.  Al mencionar el titulo, los leyentes sabrán en que idioma esta.

Answer (score 3):

Coincido con [la propuesta de Konamiman](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13/75) de mencionar los títulos de los links en inglés... cuando cabe citar el título.

Muchas veces (como en mi párrafo anterior, je :)) el enlace sirve para seguir profundizando un tema, o bien dar respaldo a lo que se dice, pero el link está *embebido* en el texto. En ese caso no veo mal agregar `(en inglés)` como aclaración.

Si bien es de esperarse que la mayor parte del material de desarrollo se encuentre en inglés, el propósito de este sitio, justamente, es ir contra esa premisa, por lo que veo muy valiosa la aclaración cuando corresponda.

En particular, en el caso mencionado en la pregunta veo correcta la aclaración.