# Etiquetas con acentos no funcionan (por lo menos en meta)

Tags: bug, estado-completado, etiquetas

Originalmente en [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9/22), puse la etiqueta de [ingles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ingles), porque no se permitían etiquetas con acentos.

Ya dijeron que se permiten, pero no están funcionando bien.

Cuando cambié la etiqueta a [inglés](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ingl%c3%a9s) (por Chrome), se convirtió en dos etiquetas, [ingl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ingl) y [s](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s).

Comment: Comprobado, al agregar una etiqueta con tilde en meta la tilde es automáticamente eliminada.