# Eliminar etiquetas [ingl] y [s]

Tags: discusión, solicitud-de-quemado

De acuerdo a esta [pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/etiquetas-con-accentos-no-funcionan-por-lo-menos-en-meta), se crearon dos etiquetas [ingl] y [s] (En Meta esSO) por error. Deberíamos eliminarlas

Answer (score 1):

Cuando una etiqueta deja de ser utilizada se elimina automáticamente a través de un cron (proceso automático) que corre cada noche. Acabo de eliminar su uso de [la única pregunta que la contenía](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9/revisions), por lo que mañana debería haber desaparecido.

Si te sorprende que en el enlace que doy aún así aparezca contenido, ten en cuenta que es una página creada dinámicamente, por lo que https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/HOLA_ESTO_ES_UNA_PRUEBA también te devolverá una página válida.

Comment: Es una etiqueta en meta

Comment: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ingl

Comment: @JhonAlx ah, ya veo. He quitado las etiquetas de esa otra pregunta, el resto de mi respuesta sigue teniendo vigencia: una vez no son usadas en ninguna pregunta, se "desactivan". Claro está, podrían volver a añadirse y, por tanto, reaparecerían, en cuyo caso se podría pedir que se bloquearan. No creo que sea necesario.