# ¿Hay algún sitio donde aparezca la resolución de bugs?

Tags: discusión, preguntas-no-contestadas

En Meta hay algunas preguntas sin responder, muchas de las cuales tratan sobre bugs, la mayoría de ellos ya corregidos.

Por ejemplo esta: [Etiquetas con acentos no funcionan (por lo menos en meta)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/23/29967)

Quizá sea bueno responder a ellas indicando que el problema fue resuelto, con un enlace que indique la fecha y resolución del bug.

¿Existe algún sitio en específico donde se indiquen los bugs que han sido resueltos?

Comment: Creo que no existe ningún sitio específico para indicar los bugs y cuando han sido resueltos aunque sería una muy buena idea para tener los bugs mucho más localizados. Actualmente hay muchos que quedan en el olvido o que se resuelven pero sus preguntas quedan abiertas como muy bien comentas.

Comment: Acerca de la parte sobre si sería bueno responder preguntas sobre [meta-tag:bugs] , creo que es suficiente con que se incluya [meta-tag:estado-completado] para indicar que el bug se ha resuelto, como es el caso del ejemplo incluido en la pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Posiblemente el sitio que más se aproxima a lo que estás buscando es https://meta.stackexchange.com en específico las preguntas con la etiqueta `bugs` pues en ese sitio se tratan temas que afecta a toda la red.

También podría ser de utilidad [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/289691) (Últimos cambios de características a Stack Exchange)

Es posible que otros buenos lugares dónde buscar sean los sitios meta de SOen, Server Fault y Super User por ser los sitios más antiguos.

Para encontrar los bugs que se han resuelto, buscar usando la etiqueta `[status-completed]`. Esta debería funcionar en todos los sitios independientemente del idioma pues se trata de una "etiqueta del sistema" que en el caso de SOes se ha marcado como sinónimo de [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado).

Cabe hacer mención que en https://stackexchange.com/filters se pueden crear filtros personalizados en los cuales se tiene la opción crear reglas para buscar en todos los sitios o en sitios específicos.

Comment: El único problema es que está en inglés.

Comment: Dice que el sitio está en venta: _**Comprar este dominio.**
stackechange.com
2017 Copyright. All Rights Reserved. 

The Sponsored Listings displayed above are served automatically by a third party. Neither the service provider nor the domain owner maintain any relationship with the advertisers. In case of trademark issues please contact the domain owner directly (contact information can be found in whois)._ ¿Es sólo un error mío o es cierto?

Comment: No, es un error en tu URL Rubén. La URL correcta es: https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @A.Cedano corregido :)

Comment: @A.Cedano: Actualicé la respuesta para agregar dos párrafos, uno sobre el uso de la etiqueta `estatus completed` y el otro sobre los filtros.