# ¿Cómo encontrar las publicaciones oficiales?

Tags: discusión, meta, stackexchange, meta-stackexchange, empresa

Hay cosas oficiales que están descritas en [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y en la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) pero no todas. Algunas han sido publicadas por el Gerente de la Comunidad, [JuanM](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m), aquí en Meta, otras en [el blog de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/), otras mas en [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

En los metas, tenemos [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), pero no todas las publicaciones oficiales tienen esa etiqueta.

¿Hay alguna forma sencilla de encontrar todas las publicaciones oficiales por ejemplo, usar un operador de búsqueda en https://stackexchange.com?

Si no hubiera una manera sencilla ¿qué cosas deberían considerarse?

- ¿Todas las publicaciones se realizan en sitios con fuente RSS?
- ¿Todas las publicaciones de usuarios con diamantes son publicaciones oficiales?
- ¿Cómo se identifica que una publicación oficial dejó de estar vigente?
- ¿Cómo se identifica que una publicación oficial ha sido actualizada?

Relacionado

- [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2093/65)
- [¿Hay algún sitio donde aparezca la resolución de bugs?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2510/65)
- [Can we be notified about official posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186614/289691)
- [When can a community blog become "official"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125894/289691)
- [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/289691)
- [How to search for questions from ♦ users (moderators / Valued Associates <--- employees )?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315528/289691)

---

## Progreso

### Buscador en Stack Exchange

Lo primero a tomar en cuenta es que el buscador en Stack Exchange es un Máquina de Búsqueda Personalizada de Google, no la "máquina tradicional" que se usa en los sitios de la red, así que los operadores como poner entre corchetes el nombre de una etiqueta no funciona de igual forma.

Recién intenté [inurl:meta official](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D). Entre los resultados llegué a un hilo sobre las respuestas oficiales a las solicitudes de características nuevas, el cual a su vez me llevó a [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263662/289691), el cual tiene la etiqueta de estado declinado.

Mi conclusión provisional es que el uso de `official` rara vez es usado para identificar publicaciones oficiales y frecuentemente usado para solicitar respuestas oficiales lo cual no implica que la habrá :D

### Perfiles de Usuario

El 31 de julio 2019 fue anunciado que los perfiles de los empleados de "la compañía" ahora están marcados como "Staff" (¿Empleado?)

Comment: Buena pregunta, realmente la documentación en [se] es algo complicado de gestionar: cambia rápido y no siempre es obvio qué está actualizado o no y qué tiene prevalencia.

Comment: Exacto, es difícil el tener en cuenta todos los cambios que ocurren entre la red de sitio......y por eso es importante el tratar esta pregunta.  La verdad no tengo una manera "oficial" que pueda sugerir. Pero, espero very que piensa la comunidad al respecto.

Comment: genial acabo de ver el perfil de [g3rv4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4), y si dica staff,maravilloso

Comment: @JuanM algunas veces me ha interesado traducir los anuncios y novedades que encuentro en el blog o Stack Exchange y publicarlos aquí aunque no sé si seria buena idea porque podría causar mucho ruido en publicaciones que salen del contexto de este sitio Meta, ¿Qué dicen? ¿Sería una buena idea?

Comment: Hola @RafaelBautistaMartinez! ¡Es una gran idea! En algunas comunidades, como los usuarios de SOru, traducen regularmente anuncios, preguntas frecuentes, publicaciones de blog importantes, etc. Creo que sería genial hablar sobre aquellos dentro de la comunidad SOes