# ¿Es inadecuado proporcionar enlaces a páginas en inglés u otro idioma distinto del español?

Tags: discusión, idiomas

Ya que este es Stack Overflow en español, me surgió la duda de si se considera incorrecto o inadecuado proporcionar enlaces a otras preguntas y/o páginas web (ya sea para respaldar la información proporcionada o para que se pueda profundizar más en el tema) que estén en inglés o en algún otro idioma.

Entiendo que para muchas personas la principal fuente son las páginas en inglés, por lo que es completamente lógico que se incluyan enlaces a estas fuentes.

Sin embargo, con respecto a los enlaces de documentación, ¿no sería mejor buscar material relacionado con la respuesta que esté también en español, para que todos puedan leerlo?

No veo mayor motivo para preferir este sitio al sitio en inglés que el poder obtener información en el idioma que uno domina, especialmente si los conocimientos que se tienen de inglés no son suficientes para entender lo que se expresa en esos enlaces.

Personalmente, considero que sería provechoso si todos pudiéramos hacer un esfuerzo para que este sitio pueda proveer la mayor cantidad de información posible en español, no solo en las respuestas, sino también en el material de lectura sugerido.

Comment: Buena pregunta; yo **lo hago** cuando no encuentro *en la primera página de resultados* lo que estoy buscando; o cuando, aún encontrándolo, no es lo suficientemente detallado para usarlo. Nunca me planteé el que no fuera *adecuado* el referenciar documentación en inglés.

Comment: **Yo lo hago** y **aclaro** que dicho enlace está en inglés, creo que ya es decisión de cada quien si le da una mirada o no, sin embargo, pienso que sigue siendo útil, por lo que no lo considero inadecuado

Comment: Creo que se sobreentiende de la respuesta a [¿Es necesario mencionar que un enlace es en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9/127)

Comment: @Mariano edité mi pregunta explayándome un poco más

Comment: @achecopar veo que orientaste la pregunta hacia una propuesta para publicar preferentemente enlaces en español (yo lo hago cada vez que puedo), pero existe mucho material de documentación oficial no traducido. ¿Hay alguna propuesta a eso, o en todo caso, no convendría aclarar que "*siempre que exista*"?

Comment: Salvo que sea una página oficial con traducción al español (como php.net/es) en general opto por vincular la referencia más completa, que suele ser en inglés. En ese sentido, priorizo calidad por sobre idioma.

Answer (score 3):

> Ya que éste es StackOverflow en español, me surgió la duda de si se considera incorrecto o inadecuado proporcionar enlaces a otras preguntas y/o páginas web (ya sea para respaldar la información proporcionada o para que se pueda profundizar más en el tema) que estén en inglés o en algún otro idioma.

Considero que si se desconoce el idioma, existen traductores que trabajan muy bien dando al menos la idea esencial. Además si uno quiere tener **mayor oportunidad** de desarrollarse como desarrollador de software, **saber inglés es vital**, la documentación de X componente, lenguajes de programación lo vas a encontrar en dicho idioma en un altísimo porcentaje. Creo que dando enlaces en inglés ayuda a motivar a que los usuarios adquieran dicho idioma y para colaborar con ello, generalmente publico enlaces como https://memrise.com - https://duolingo.com - https://engvid.com y el gran canal de Youtube: 1-2-3 inglés, definitivamente se los recomiendo.

> Entiendo que para muchas personas la principal fuente son las páginas en inglés, por lo que es completamente lógico que se incluyan enlaces a estas fuentes.

Totalmente cierto, la cantidad y/o calidad de recursos que hay en inglés superan notablemente a los que hay en español. Gente de Francia, Italia, Alemania, India, China, Japón y otros países de diversos idiomas que tienen blogs en inglés con muy buen material.

> Sin embargo, con respecto a los enlaces de documentación, ¿no sería mejor buscar material relacionado con la respuesta que esté también en español, para que todos puedan leerlo?

¿A qué tipo de documentación te refieres? La que hay en internet, tiende a ser primero en inglés. Si hay en español, de hecho que sería bueno. En lo personal repito lo mencionado en el punto 1.

> No veo mayor motivo para preferir este sitio al sitio en inglés que el poder obtener información en el idioma que uno domina, especialmente si los conocimientos que se tienen de inglés no son suficientes para entender lo que se expresa en esos enlaces.

Es decisión personal, llevo años usando SOen y recién hace casi 2 que me registré y no llego ni a 300 puntos, por otro lado hace más de 1 año que colaboro constantemente por estos lares con todo el gusto del mundo :D

> Personalmente, considero que sería provechoso si todos pudiéramos hacer un esfuerzo para que este sitio pueda proveer la mayor cantidad de información posible en español, no solo en las respuestas, sino también en el material de lectura sugerido.

Tienes razón, dependerá de qué tanta información en español conozcan los usuarios para que se pueda recomendar, en mi caso, es poca.

> Detalle extra:

Lo más quemado/rayado/loco que he hecho por pura curiosidad ha sido ver una demo de un despliegue de un sistema hecho PHP en Azure, en coreano, sí, en coreano, considera que tengo un vocabulario de unas 5 palabras y un par de frases y ahí quedó.

Finalmente, respondiendo al título:

> ¿Es inadecuado proporcionar enlaces a páginas en inglés u otro idioma distinto del español?

Dudo que sea inadecuado. Lo que siento que sí es inadecuado es copiar y pegar código como respuesta que tienen comentarios en inglés //deberían al menos ser traducidos.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Cabe resaltar que los enlaces sirven solo para ahondar en mayor información sobre el tema, por ende los enlaces pueden apuntar a recursos en inglés. Pero el contenido brindado en las respuestas debe ser principalmente **en español**. Si se cita contenido en inglés u otro idioma, debe proveerse **la traducción** que permita a los lectores comprender la cita y su significado.

Comment: gracias mi estimado, ahí le vamos con todo el power 2.0! :D

Answer (score 3):

La página de SOes se espera que el contenido sea en Español (de ahí el nombre) así que si algo no está en ese idioma opino que DEBE indicarse.

Es un gran problema la falta de material específico en Español y hay poco que podamos hacer para resolverlo... salvo traducir el contenido nosotros mismos.

Mi aproximación es usar enlaces en Español siempre que estén disponibles, la página [cppreference.com [image]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) permite *forzar* la traducción del contenido a Español cambiando la URL:

- Documentación sobre `std::basic_istream` en Inglés: [`http://`**`en`**`.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).
- Documentación sobre `std::basic_istream` en Español: [`http://`**`es`**`.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).

Pero realiza una traducción automática que suele ser (siendo amable) confusa. Así que cuando el material disponible no es el mejor, opino que añadir una traducción es lo mejor que puede hacese.

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo. Lo mismo pasa con la web de PHP, por ejemplo http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php vs http://php.net/manual/es/function.strstr.php